# Ошибка при вызове функции main: NameError: name 'N' is not defined

Tags: python

```
def check_input():
    try:
        N = input("Введите N:")
        K = input("Введите K:")
        M = input("Введите M:")
except(TypeError, ValueError):
    print("Введено неверное значение!")
else:
    return N, K, M


def main(N, K, M):
    i = 0
    while N != 0:
        if N % K == 0 and K > 1 and N > M and N/K > M:
            N = N/K
            i = i + 1
            print("N:" + str(N))
            print("Действие:" + str(i))
        elif N != 0 and N > M:
            N = N - 1
            i = i + 1
            print("N:" + str(N))
            print("Действие:" + str(i))
        elif N == M:
            N = int(N)
            print("N = " + str(N) + ";M = " + str(M))
            print("Мин. кол-во действий:" + str(i))
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
check_input()
main(N, K, M)
```

Comment: N, K, M = check_input()

Comment: какой смысл задавать вопрос и забивать?

Answer (score -1):

я даже не знаю с чего тут начать, ну **во первых** я не знаю как вы вообще запустили код, когда у вас нарушена индентация:

```
def ...():
    your code
```

**во вторых** конструкция try тут не уместна, ибо вы не поймаете ошибку при вводе(типовую, а уж тем более ошибку значения), так еще и *return* в *else*, в общем жуть.

**ТРЕТЬЕ** и основное: имена N,M,K - локальные, а не глобальные. у каждой функции или класса есть свое пространство имен, и переменные объявленные в этих пространствах не распространятся на **весь код** если грубо. посему - либо вызывайте функцию от того, что вернула первая функция

```
main(check_input())
```

либо считывайте переменные в глобальном *namespace* и тогда вызывайте

```
main(N, K, M)
```

как вы и планировали